# Size Exclusion Cromatography - How Does Detector Determine Molecular Mass Distribution in Polymers?

Tags: polymers

In materials I am using it is written that detectors in SE cromatography determine concentration of polymer molecules of particular mass on exit of column by measuring index of refraction.

How is concentration of particular mass in mobile phase on exit of the column connected with molecular mass distribution of polymers since SE cromatography is used to determine such distribution?

Comment: It is explained very nicely here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Size-exclusion_chromatography#Analysis

Comment: A refractive index detector cannot determine or find the molecular weight of anything, it just measures refractive index changes of the eluent.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Wikipedia states that spectroscopy is used to determine concentration of each molecule in the eluent, but that other techniques are used to determine what these are which in terms of polymers means molecular mass and structure. Spectroscopy does quantitative analysis while other techniques do qualitative.

Comment: One should have a standard and elaborate based on results. The connection is due to the fact that known stuff has been measured before. Nothing here is a single reading like measuring T with a thermometer....